# ( PHP ) How to xpath query the inner text of xs:documentation?

Tags: php, xpath, xsd

How to xpath query the inner text of xs:documentation?

```
$xsd = simplexml_load_file('my_xsd_file.xsd');

// I have tried:
$xsd->xpath("./xs:complexType[1]/xs:annotation/xs:documentation");

$xsd->xpath("./xs:complexType[1]/xs:annotation/xs:documentation/text()");

$xsd->xpath("./xs:complexType[1]/xs:annotation/xs:documentation[text()]");
```

All the above return an empty object.

**UPDATE:**

- The **my_xsd_file.xsd** can be found at [gist.github.com/drupalista-br/9666339](https://gist.github.com/drupalista-br/9666339)
- Printing out this call `$xsd->getDocNamespaces();` returns:

  `Array
  (
      [ds] => http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#
      [xs] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
      [] => http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe
  )`

So it seems to me that the namespaces are correctly registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug on PHP 5.4 xpath https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62203

I tested my code on PHP 5.3 and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You must also register the namespace prefix `xs` with its matching namespace URI.

```
$xsd->registerXPathNamespace('xs', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
```

Additionally, you omitted the first axis step for the root element `<xs:schema/>`.

```
$xsd->xpath("/xs:schema/xs:complexType[1]/xs:annotation/xs:documentation");
```

Comment: my_xsd_file.xsd can be found at https://gist.github.com/drupalista-br/9666339 .

I've printed out the result of $xsd->getDocNamespaces(); and this came up:

https://gist.github.com/drupalista-br/9666499

So xs seems to be already registered. Are you able to see something that I might be missing out?

Comment: This function only returns all namespaces that occur in the XML; it does not mean these are already registered for querying. They could even use another prefix for the same URI.

Comment: I've done the registration and testing anyway, just like you suggested, but I still get an empty object.

To make sure the object returned was the right one, I added a test attribute <xs:documentation test='test'>. The attribute is successfully returned.

Comment: I've just driven down to a client of mine and tested my original code. It works just fine. My guts are telling me that this whole thing has something to do with PHP version. Can't remember which PHP version I got in my machine back in my office, I reckon it is 5.4.x, here at my client's machine it is 5.3.10. Going to do more testings, let you now later. Thank you very much for now.